Can't set value of input element using Selenium
I'm trying to update the value of an input element using python and selenium webdriver.  This is on Windows 10 using Edge.  The page loads normally, and I can interact with the element using keyboard & mouse, but when I try to set the value using code I get the "element not interactable" error.  Code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
edge_service = webdriver.EdgeService(executable_path=edge_driver_path)
edge_driver = webdriver.Edge(service=edge_service)
edge_driver.get(url)
time.sleep(15)
elements, macroponent_bs = edge_driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//*"), None
for element in elements:
    if element.tag_name.startswith("macroponent"):
        macroponent_bs = element.tag_name
        break
if macroponent_bs:
    script = "return document.querySelector('" + macroponent_bs + "')" + \
             ".shadowRoot.querySelector('iframe')"
    iframe = edge_driver.execute_script(script=script)
    edge_driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
element = edge_driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value=element_id)
print(f"Element value is >{element.get_attribute('value')}<")
print(f"Element is_enabled, is_displayed = {element.is_enabled()}, {element.is_displayed()}")
element.send_keys("Hello")

Output:
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65277/devtools/browser/5c5b2c22-eade-45c7-a8ee-2b234dae3f76
[38728:37308:1104/075027.679:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(127)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.
[38728:37308:1104/075032.464:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(127)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.
Element value is ><
Element is_enabled, is_displayed = True, False

Error from send_keys:
Exception has occurred: ElementNotInteractableException (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: on_btn_debug)
Message: element not interactable (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=130.0.2849.68)


is that shadowRoot closed or open ??

@jak_bin sorry I don't understand what a shadowRoot is?

There is too many problems to write a proper answer, but here are some tips:
Use WebDriverWait:
For waiting the page to load:
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
        lambda d: d.execute_script("return document.readyState") == "complete"
    )
    print("Page has fully loaded.")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load.")

For waiting that an element is available:
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, value))
    )
    print("Element is visible.")
    return element
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for the element to be visible.")
    return None

If you want a more precise answer, please add an url. You could also use a debugger.

Unfortunately the URL won't be accessible unless the user is logged into my employers work network.  I'm confused as to why the element returns False for is_displayed() call when it is clearly visible on the page.  Also I'm able to interact with it, and enter a value, using the keyboard.  For some reason webdriver can't send characters to it.

This is probably because you are not in the right iframe... In this case, debugging would be your key
